# oracle SQL.merge multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I have data as below

```
 A     B     
 =     1    
 =     2    
 !=    3    
 =     4    
 !=    5
```

I need to put these into one coloumn so that all '!=' are below "=" data and with '!=' as dummy row only if  there exists row with '!=' in coloumn A

```
   1
   2
   4
   !=
   3
   5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `union all` to get all the values you want in the rows.  Add a column to specify the placement.  The order by that column:

```
select value
from (select cast(B as varchar2(255)) as value, 1 as which
      from t
      where A <> '!='
      union all
      select '!=', 2 from dual
      union all
      select cast(B as varchar2(255)) , 3
      from t
      where A = '!='
    ) s
order by which;
```

EDIT:

For the revised version:

```
select value
from ((select cast(B as varchar2(255)) as value, 1 as which
       from t
       where A <> '!='
      ) union all
      (select '!=', 2 from dual where exists (select 1 from t where A = '!=')
      ) union all
      (select cast(B as varchar2(255)), 3
       from t
       where A = '!='
      )
    ) s
order by which;
```

Comment: I my question needs to be edited.. '!=' row should be there should be there only if there is Data with "!=" in coloumn A.

Comment: @Gordon won't this get error... Union all should be having same data type throughout right, here we are having numbers partial having a character...

Comment: @SarathiKamaraj . . . I put that in.  However, it is not obvious to me that `B` is not already a character string.  The OP says nothing about the type.

Comment: Thanks.. My Coloumn B data was anyways Varchar2 :)